# Determine song being played on iPhone by third-party app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to determine the title of the song currently being played on an iPhone. I know I can use the following code to find out what is playing if the native Apple app is playing the music but how do I find the title of a song if its being played from Spotify or some other music playing app?

```
MPMediaItem *nowPlayingItem = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
NSString *itemTitle = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
```

Comment: You can't. That's information private to the playing app.

Comment: @weber did you manage to find a solution? I'm currently struggling with the same issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't get title of song if its playing in some other app!

Edit 1 -

You can't do that because Apple has a very strict policy that runs every app in its own little sandbox that cannot access any other applications data.

-- Thanks Emil ...

Comment: Please always put comments if you are going to down vote a question or answer!

Comment: I did not downvote, but you should provide some more details in your answer. For example: "You can't do that because Apple has a very strict policy that runs every app in its own little sandbox that cannot access any other applications data.".

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the app supports iOS 5's `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, you could do this:

```
NSDictionary *info = [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] nowPlayingInfo];
NSString *title = [info valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
```

Comment: this does not work but it looks like I could use the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter if it were possible to programmatically create a UIEvent with the type UIEventTypeRemoteControl. any idea if that's possible?