# Get current playing song from Spotify iOS app

Tags: spotify, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I'm trying to get info about the current playing song in Spotify iOS app. The scenario is as follows: Open Spotify iOS app, start playing a song. Put the app in background and open my iOS app. Is there any way I could get the song playing on Spotify, in my iOS app?

I have tried using the nowPlayingItem property as described in this post, but it didn't work: [On iPhone: Find out what song is currently playing? (in the iPod music player)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917014/on-iphone-find-out-what-song-is-currently-playing-in-the-ipod-music-player)

I have tried using the [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo as described in this post, but it didn't work: [Is there a way to access the currently played track while the iPhone is connected to an accessory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157211/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-currently-played-track-while-the-iphone-is-connecte)

I have seen the same question asked in this post on apple developer forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/903640#903640.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Have you found a viable solution?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine song being played on iPhone by third-party app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542854/determine-song-being-played-on-iphone-by-third-party-app)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate because that question is asking for a generic solution, so any answers to that question can not take into account any possibly Spotify-specific APIs.

Comment: This may help you: [Get meta data displayed in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter's nowPlayingInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534939/get-meta-data-displayed-in-mpnowplayinginfocenters-nowplayinginfolock-screen-a)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution in Swift 3:

```
let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
if let mediaItem = player.nowPlayingItem {
    let title: String = mediaItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as! String
    let albumTitle: String = mediaItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as! String
    let artist: String = mediaItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as! String

    print("\(title) on \(albumTitle) by \(artist)")
}
```

Note that starting from iOS 10, you must set a description string for `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` in the Info.plist in order to get access to the user's music.

`mediaItem` will be an instance of [`MPMediaItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html) if there is something playing. You can access the media item's attributes using the `value(forProperty:)` method. This methods takes a property. The properties are defined in the documentation for `MPMediaItem under the heading "General Media Item Property Keys".

Comment: This only works with the iOS player. With third-party apps like Spotify, `mediaItem` is `nil`.

Comment: I'm looking for this too, is there anyway to access 3rd party apps' now playing info?

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of the Spotify iOS SDK (introduced around Sep 2018) you can now subscribe for player events and detect when a new track starts playing.

For more info check their [the quick-start tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios/quick-start/).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, Apple doesn't allow program's to share data (for security reasons). So maybe that's the problem.

Comment: You should provide where did you grab that info.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to connect spotify app to your app then you can get from
`SPTAppRemotePlayerState?.track.uri` from this you get uri

Comment: Try and provide more detail in your answers, perhaps a better example