# Get meta data displayed in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter's nowPlayingInfo(lock screen and remote control)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, mpnowplayinginfocenter

Thanks for noticing this question. I want to do something about music recommendation, and what I am doing now is leveraging `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`'s `nowPlayingInfo`, like this:

```
NSDictionary *metaData = [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] nowPlayingInfo];
NSString *songTitle = metaData[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSString *albumnTitle = metaData[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
NSString *artist = metaData[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
```

But it always returns nil when "Music" app is playing music in background. 
I looked up the related documents, it says

```
 MPNowPlayingInfoCenter provides an interface for setting the current now 
 playing information for the application.
 The default center holds now playing info about the current application
```

Seems there is no way to get other app's `nowPlayingInfo` through `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`. So are there any other ways to get other app's music meta data displayed in remote control/lock screen? Thanks!

Comment: why you want to get other app's data ?

Comment: @Desmond Because I want to recommend user some information based on his/her interest. Music is a good tip.

Comment: hi i had a go to try on getting the the nowplayinginfo but to no avail.

i'm not sure if u could get the info as all app are sandboxed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what iPod currently is playing

```
MPMusicPlayerController* player = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
//get now playing item
MPMediaItem*item = [player nowPlayingItem];
// get the title of song
NSString* titleStr = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSLog(@"titlestr %@",titleStr);
```

Comment: `[player nowPlayingItem]` is returning nil for me

Comment: @hodgesmr Are you sure the Music (iPod) app is playing, and not something else like Podcasts?

Comment: It won't work with third-party apps like Spotify, only the iOS player.