# iOS : is it really impossible to get info of current track being played in third-party apps (like Spotify)?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, spotify, mpmusicplayercontroller

So far, I have red many conflicting answers about this.

In [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512182/get-current-playing-song-from-spotify-ios-app), it is said to use:

```
let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
if let mediaItem = player.nowPlayingItem {
    // ...
}
```

However, this only works with the iOS player. If the current song is being played by Spotify for example, `mediaItem` will be `nil`.

I understand that Apple's policy doesn't allow to access any other application's data. The only thing I am able to do right now is to know if a song is playing from another player with the help of `AVAudioPlayer`'s `secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint` and `isOtherAudioPlaying`.

I want to know, however, if there is another way to access it, like using `Spotify` framework? (I am absolutely non familiar with it, that's just making assumptions).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about iOS but the current track can be read from Spotify on a Mac via AppleScript. I use this technique from Objective C. If you're interested I can post the code.

Spotify publish their API for AppleScript here https://developer.spotify.com/applescript-api/

If you're looking for a generic way of determining what is playing then I think that you will be disappointed. Each application will have a different way of retrieving this information.

Answer (score 0):

So yes and no. If you want to specifically only check if Spotify is playing, then perhaps the Spotify iOS SDK provides functionality for such a thing. I really don't know about that SDK's functionality.

I would venture to guess that your actual goal is to see if any third party framework is playing; Pandora, Tidal, Apple Music, Amazon Prime Music, etc. In which case, you would need a framework for each one that provided such functionality.

Apps are sandboxed from each other for security, so yes, there is no way to tell the current track information other than if you have the framework in place and it provides that functionality.